# How do i compile all contact's phone numbers into one cell - using CNContact

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

My code I am using to source the contact's phone number is below, what i would like to do is have all the contacts phone numbers (landline, mobiles etc) shown together, example 0402 000 000, 618 802336, 0423 000 000 (together in the one textField)

**My code below**

```
// Retrieve contact details ---------------------------
    @IBAction func show(_ sender: Any) {
        let contacVC = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contacVC.delegate = self
        self.present(contacVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {

        print(contact.phoneNumbers)
        let numbers = contact.phoneNumbers.first
        print((numbers?.value)?.stringValue ?? "")
        self.Phone.text = "\((numbers?.value)?.stringValue ?? "")"
            }

    func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display all phone number as like below

```
let contact = CNContact()
let numbers = contact.phoneNumbers.compactMap { $0.value.stringValue }
self.Phone.text = numbers.joined(separator: ", ")
```